# Text getting cut inside polygon function and is not accepting any style commands

Tags: html, css

Hi so i was experimenting with some new concepts of css where i came around the polygon function and thought to implement in a web page so i did and everything was good and all but when i added text inside it i went outside the desired shape and its color or font wasn't changing. I want a look like what we get by using the margin-outside function can someone please help me with it

[image]

**HTML**

```
<section id="side1">
    <div class="leftbox"></div>
    <div class="rightbox">
        <h2>Welcome</h2><br>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel ultrices tellus.
            Fusce eu egestas nulla, sit amet sodales lorem. Sed volutpat laoreet libero varius rhoncus.
            Curabitur malesuada, purus vel varius ornare, erat leo consectetur mi, et consequat tortor
            sapien quis nulla. Vivamus faucibus tincidunt sapien, in rutrum arcu auctor sed. Interdum
            et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse consectetur, eros at
            vehicula semper, libero odio lacinia velit, id rhoncus ligula sem id ipsum. Morbi in 
            cursus enim. Aenean nisl ligula, pulvinar vitae metus ac, euismod rutrum dui.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS for boxes**

```
#side1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    background: url(architecture-building-club-587840.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: -220px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 1;
}

.leftbox {
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 40% 0%, 25% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.rightbox {
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(19% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(19% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```css
#side1{
  height: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  background: url(architecture-building-club-587840.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: -220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.leftbox{
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 40% 0%, 25% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 55% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.rightbox{
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(19% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(19% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<section id="side1">
  <div class="leftbox"></div>
  <div class="rightbox">
    <h2>Welcome</h2><br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel ultrices tellus.
      Fusce eu egestas nulla, sit amet sodales lorem. Sed volutpat laoreet libero varius rhoncus.
      Curabitur malesuada, purus vel varius ornare, erat leo consectetur mi, et consequat tortor
      sapien quis nulla. Vivamus faucibus tincidunt sapien, in rutrum arcu auctor sed. Interdum
      et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse consectetur, eros at
      vehicula semper, libero odio lacinia velit, id rhoncus ligula sem id ipsum. Morbi in 
      cursus enim. Aenean nisl ligula, pulvinar vitae metus ac, euismod rutrum dui.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achive? You want text to not be cut like on your screen? And to have it inside shape of your container?

Comment: You'd need to use `shape-outside` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside rather than a clip-path

Comment: Also, you say "its color or font aren't changing", but there is no attempt in the code to change the color or font.

Comment: yeah i want the text to not cut it and sta inside the shape of the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clip path does not give the object a boundary to keep child objects inside of it. It simply slices the object via the parameters you pass into it. Kind of like border radius does when you set a large  enough value to impact the content.  Anythinge outside  of those parameters will be sliced off and hidden. You can use CSS shape outside or skew to change the parent object however skew will skew the children as well. Hope this helps.

```
img {
    height: 550px;
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 0% 0%, 0 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLwVjO)

Comment: so how do i fix it an alternatives?

Comment: @adityaprakash from what you described above you would use the technique Paulie D described and use shape-outside: polygon(10px 10px, 20px 20px, 30px 30px); obviously you will need to adjust the values. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside

Comment: where to use the value i used it in the text box where i used polygon but nothing worked can u please post an example of some sorts

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to my computer right now if you give me a few hours I'll post an example let me know if you get it figured out before then

Comment: Ok it would be a great help real headache when they don't tell every detail about something in there online courses

Comment: So basically I need to add a blank pic inside the the transformed text-box and give it shape-outside lol why didn't I thought that before

Comment: yup, just make sure the image is big enough to cover all the wrapping your text will do. best way to manipulate the shape is to pull it up in your dev tools and play with the numbers. Also be sure to check browser support because this is not supported by IE or Edge. Just let me know if you need anything else.  If you are good mark for completion.  good luck

Comment: You are very welcome,  keep on coding.  Sorry I meant mark as answered (when your finished) please and thank you

Comment: my bad forgot to mark the answer ..thanks for the help it worked but problem arises when i zoom in and zoom out the page guess shapes like that arent meant to work fine. I wanna learn more about this particular segment of css can u suggest any book or resource available for it if u know about any would be a great help and thanks again for ur precious time

Comment: No worries thank you and again you are very welcome, a good one for your particular area: https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/ and then there is always https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes

Comment: Thanks again will check it have a nice day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186810/discussion-between-kjek-code-and-aditya-prakash).